# Mysql table corrupt?

Tags: mysql, count, records

I have a table with two text fields, both having an index of length = 4.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM `mytable` WHERE `field1` = ‘blue’;
```

shows me 4 records and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM `mytable` WHERE `field2` = ‘blue’;
```

shows me another 4 records (different result)

But:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM `mytable` WHERE `field1` = ‘blue’ OR `field2` = ‘blue’;
```

shows me only 5 records! Why???

When I use `DESCRIBE SELECT` etc. (without COUNT) it tells me the following:

**id    select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  mytable index_merge field1,field2   field1,field2   6,6 NULL    495 Using sort_union(field1,field2); Using where**

How is this possible? Why can’t I see all 8 records?

(Note: I have replaced the table names because the real names are Dutch)

If you need more table information, I will post it.

Please help.

Comment: The results where field1 is blue or field2 are blue just might overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM mytable WHERE field1 = ‘blue’ AND field2 <> ‘blue’;
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM mytable WHERE field2 = ‘blue’ AND field1 <> ‘blue’;
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM mytable WHERE field2 = ‘blue’ AND field1 = ‘blue’;
```

Comment: The first query: 8 records
The second query: 8 records
The third query: 0 records

Comment: Are you sure, you have all the `field1` and `field2` and `=`and `<>`right?

Answer (score 0):

Just do `'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field1 = ‘blue’ OR field2 = ‘blue’;'` and you will see your problem :) which is actually not a problem because `field1` and `field2` could both have value `blue` in a row

Comment: There's no record having the same value in both fields.

SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM mytable WHERE field2 = 'blue' AND field1 = 'blue';

shows 0 records.